# What can i pass in as placeholder for first argument in map function Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

This is my map function, it's not registering *i* as the index because i think the map function needs element as first element

```
{listArray.map((i: number) => (
    <IRServiceAlertRulesListItem addListItem={addListItem} listArray={listArray} key={i} />
  ))}
```

Getting this error in my console
**Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`.**

Comment: What does each item look like in `listArray`? It seems as if you're expecting a number but they're actually objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `i` variable inside your map function is an object (maybe something is wrong with the type `i: number` here?), you cannot use Object as a key in React.
Use `index` instead

```
{listArray.map((i, index) => (
    <IRServiceAlertRulesListItem addListItem={addListItem} listArray={listArray} key={index} />
  ))}
```

If you have a unique property inside each `listArray` element, use it instead of `index`.